# VS Code not outputing to "Output Tab"

Tags: c, visual-studio-code

I've been tring to program on VS Code in C for quite a while now but i can't get the output to go in the correct spot.
As you can see in this really short test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    printf("This is a test \n");
}
```

,and the adjacent image, the output goes to the debug console and not the output tab, or even the terminal
Does anyone have any clue as to why this is happening?
I'm using CGG to compile it

[image]

Comment: The output window is used by vscode features, vscode built-in extensions & vscode 3rd party extensions. Not for your project. You should be using the Debug Console or the Terminal to log output. If you look to the right of the output panel there is a drop-down menu, if you drop that menu open you will see a list of VSCode processes, a logger for tasks, some feature loggers, and if your like me, a crap ton of extension loggers.

Comment: Voting to close as this isn't reproducible, and IMO falls under typo.

Comment: The fact that I voted to close doesn't mean anything bad, FYI. It just means that this isn't a valid question for stack overflow, because it doesn't have a solution. Its a mistake. Personally I make mistakes daily. To best help other community members, its best to keep only solvable posts in the stack overflow DB.